# TuxOnIce freezes on hibernation

Tags: hibernate, tuxonice

When I hibernate TuxOnIce freezes, showing "Writing kernel & process data"
I'm using ubuntu 15.04

What could be wrong?

Solution:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate#swsusp

You can try the swsusp (the default) if the system hibernate but then powers on like it wasn't hibernating, you just need to change your grub file to do so, as it says in the link. If it doesn't work you can try the uswsusp and as a last resort the TuxOnIce, I've tried all three, none worked for me, then I returned to the default one and changed my grub file as it said to, solved!